# Where is the global address list stored in AD?

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

Where is the GAL actually stored in AD?

I always assumed in was inside of the GC. Is this correct? I know clients must query the GC in order to access the GAL, but is the GAL inside of the GC?

Where would I go to view it in adsiedit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ADSIEDIT:

Configuration [.contoso.com]

◦CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com

◦CN=Services

◦CN=Microsoft Exchange

◦CN=OrganizationName

◦CN=Address Lists Container

◦CN=All Global Address Lists

[Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535387(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: That's weird, In adsiedit I can expand Configuration>Services>Microsoft Exchange, but under that I only see one node "CN=MYDOMAIN". Should I have all of these objects (OrganizationName,Address Lists Container, All Global Address Lists) under the Microsoft Exchange object because I do not see them.

Comment: Could it be that I do not have access to view those objects?

Comment: @red888 does get-globaladdresslist -Identity "Default Global Address List" | format-list return something ? It's indeed strange, as it's supposed to be there, and like you told, you need an admin account to view. (not sure if exchange admin or domain enterprise admin there)